# PHP, get result set in two variables from single mysql_query

Tags: php

This is not working

```
$restab=mysql_query("SELECT `tb_id`, `tb_head` FROM `tbs` where dashboard_id=$dash_board_id") or die(mysql_error());
$resbody=$restab;
```

This is working

```
$restab=mysql_query("SELECT `tb_id`, `tb_head` FROM `tbs` where dashboard_id=$dash_board_id") or die(mysql_error());
$resbody=mysql_query("SELECT `tb_id`, `tb_head` FROM `tbs` where dashboard_id=$dash_board_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why do you actually want to duplicate the query resultset?

Comment: i have to use 2 while loops at different places

Comment: Use mysql_data_seek($restab, 0) to reset the result pointer before the second loop - [see PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Comment: But switch to MySQLi rather than use the deprecated MySQL extension, and the equivalent to reset the resultset pointer with MySQLi is `data_seek(0)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you reuse a mysql result set in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638014/can-you-reuse-a-mysql-result-set-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `tb_id`, `tb_head` FROM `tbs` where dashboard_id=$dash_board_id")
    or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    .... do some stuff
}

mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    .... do some more stuff
}
```

But as the mysql extension is deprecated, you really should be switching to mysqli or pdo, and learning to use bind variables

Answer (score 0):

**Major update:**

Create var:

```
$query = "SELECT `tb_id`, `tb_head` FROM `tbs` where dashboard_id=$dash_board_id";
```

Call function multiple times:

```
$resbody = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$restab = mysql_query($query);
```

Do not use deprecated function nex time, take a look at `MYSQLI` or `PDO`

Comment: not working..! i don't know why i stuck in this today .

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to duplicate the result object, I propose to `clone` the object using [php clone function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Something like this

```
$resbody = clone $restab;
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object
i am beginner please clarify it.. your answer looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make the same query again, use 
`mysql_data_seek($restab,0)`

And then use it again. The internal row pointer will be reset.
More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_data_seek.asp

Comment: You'd be better linking to the official PHP docs rather than w3fools